# Will a MySql module for Python 3.4 work with 3.5?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

All of the MySql modules I've found are compatible with Python 2.7 or 3.4, but none with 3.5. Any way I can use a MySql module with the newest Python version?

**ANSWER:**

The regular Python versions of mysql-connector-python would not work, but the rf version did.

python -m pip install mysql-connector-python-rf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python tries hard to be forward compatible.  A pure-python module written for 3.4 should work with 3.5; a binary package may work, you just have to try it and see.